# SQL - If Select returns nothing then do another Select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently trying to do an SQL query that can detect if a SELECT query returns nothing, and then do another one if that is the case.

Here is what I mean:

```
IF SELECT * FROM table WHERE criteria = criteria RETURNS NO ROWS
THEN SELECT * FROM table WHERE criteria2 = criteria2
```

Is this possible? I don't think that an empty reply counts as "null" so I have a bit of a trouble with that.

Comment: What specific database are you using?

Comment: I'm using Postgresql. The solution below worked with it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this in one statement, assuming the columns are the same:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE criteria = criteria 
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE criteria2 = criteria2 AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE criteria = criteria);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this actually worked nicely. You're beast. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE criteria2 = criteria2
and not exists (
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE criteria = criteria
)
union all
SELECT * FROM table WHERE criteria = criteria;
```

Here `NOT EXISTS` ensures that either part of the UNION ALL is returned. If the second `criteria = criteria` passes, then `NOT EXISTS` will return false and hence, only second part of the above query returns result. If it doesn't, it means, there are no rows with `criteria = criteria` and NOT EXISTS will return true and hence, only the first part return data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Gurwinder. :) Made it easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
I Did it like this

WITH
    First AS (
        SELECT t1.<field1>
            FROM <schema1>.<table1> t1
            WHERE
                <criteria1>
            [Other SQL Queries Options]
            OFFSET 0
            LIMIT 1
    ),
    Second AS (
        SELECT t2.<field2>
            FROM <schema2>.<table2> t2
            WHERE
                <criteria2>
            [Other SQL Queries Options]
            OFFSET 0
            LIMIT 1
    )

SELECT <field1>
    FROM First
UNION ALL
SELECT <field2> as <same name as field1>
    FROM Second
    WHERE NOT exists(
        SELECT 1 FROM First
    )
;
```